# Bootstrap 5 Card with Tabs and content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to achieve this effect: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab&stacked=h
with Bootstrap 5 and using it inside a Bootstrap Card.

#### I've first tried without cards

I've literally copied the above example and it's not working https://jsfiddle.net/zqdsLeyj/

I've put my whole page in the JS above, but this is the part that I am trying to implement right now:

```html
<div class="container network_wrapper col-sm p-2 ">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>HOME</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 1</h3>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
                ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
                laudantium, totam rem
                aperiam.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 3</h3>
            <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta
                sunt explicabo.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Nav and Tabs styling or functionality do not work for some reason.

#### What I want to achieve is to have Tabs inside a Card:

Something like this, which obviously doesn't work:

```html
<div class="container network_wrapper col-sm p-2 ">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="card-title">Network Settings</h5>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="true" data-toggle="tab"
                        href="#dhcp">DHCP</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#static">Static</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form class="card-body" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="dhcp>
                <p class=" card-text">Change DHCP Network settings.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="static>
                <p class=" card-text">Change Static Network settings.</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried this: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/bootstrap+card+with+working+nav+tabs without avail.

I haven't tried using JS and I'm not looking for a JS solution, because the functionality is surely built in Bootstrap 5. I just don't understand how to use it.

I've added bootstrap CSS (inside `head` tab) and JS (at the end of the `body` tag) to my HTML file:

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 5 are very different. W3schools and other external site are not always dependable learning resources. Instead refer to the [official Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: I could not find anything in the docs. The examples in the Bootstrap docs are half-done. I could not find one example for what I am trying to achieve. That's why I have posted here. I've just started to use Bootstrap and it's literally impossible to know the difference between Bootstrap versions. I have started with v5. How could I know anything prior to it ?

Comment: The docs show a clear [example of working tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior). *How could I know anything prior to it ?* __ [using the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/) instead of unreliable 3rd party tutorials.

Comment: @Zim I have to do an interface very fast and I can't afford the time to read the differences between v4 and v5. I am also sorry that I could not find the example of working tabs. Thank you for your help. I will read the docs more thoroughly from now on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix the improper HTML structure, and follow the guidance in the Bootstrap docs. Bootstrap 5 uses `data-bs-` not `data-` atttributes...

```
       <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="card-title">Network Settings</h5>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" data-bs-tabs="tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="true" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#dhcp">DHCP</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#static">Static</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <form class="card-body tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="dhcp">
                    <p class="card-text">Change DHCP Network settings.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="static">
                    <p class=" card-text">Change Static Network settings.</p>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
            </form>
       </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/t6GGNuV2yb

Comment: I did follow the guides from Bootstrap, but their examples are half-baked. I couldn't find one example that suits my needs. Also, in your example, on the first page load, the DHCP  tab is first active, but it's `p` tag doesn't show.

Comment: IMO, w3schools examples are half-baked and old. They're not updated unlike the docs which are always up to date. Anyway, the `tab-pane` also needs to set to have the `active` class if you want it to show initially. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. w3school examples pop up more frequent when searching for web-dev stuff. The problem is that I can't differentiate between Bootstrap versions because I have just started working with it and the majority of examples are made with older versions of Bootstrap, while I am using the newest one.