# Django template with BS5 tab-pane for-loop

Tags: django, tabs, bootstrap-5

So I am trying to make a page with tabs and corresponding panes.
I used the original BS5-code and also found some guides like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043604/bootstrap-5-card-with-tabs-and-content)

I adapted the code to fit to the Django template, but it acts quite strangely: Initially no pane is shown when selecting another tab and then the first one again all panes are shown simultaneously.

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="specimen_tab" data-bs-tabs="tabs">
                    {% for a_s in analyte_specimen %}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link{% if forloop.first %} active"
                               aria-current="true {% endif %}"
                               data-bs-toggle="tab"
                               href="#pane-{{ a_s.specimen.sg_id }}">{{ a_s.specimen.name }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>


                <div class="tab-content card-body" id="specimen_tabContent">
                    {% for a_s in analyte_specimen %}
                        <div class="tab-pane fade{% if forloop.first %} active{% endif %}"
                             id="pane-{{ a_s.specimen.sg_id }}">
                           <-- Content here -->
                        </div>
                           ......
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the rendeted html is correct? Your description sounds like the panes do not have unique id attributes.

Is sg_id a unique field of your specimen model? Have ypu tried just using specimen.pk instead to make the pane id and link hrwf? That at least should give unique id attributes to the div's.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
Firstly, I had (for whatever reason 2 different BS5-versions loaded) - this reolved part of th issue. Now the first pane is shown correctly, but when clicking on the second, third, etch no content is shown. 
Indeed when inspecting the produced html it seems that the "active" attribute is correctly shifted to the tab I am clicking on but the according pane does not recieve this attribute and therefore is not shown.
Any ideas?